# MongoDB aggregated query for conversation messages

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, chat

I am working on chat and I want to get conversations order by created date and messages order by created in a single array of object. This query gets conversation with messages of limit 10 order by date.

```
db.models.conversations.aggregate([
        { $match: { 'participants': Number(uid) } },
        { $sort: { 'created': -1 } },
        { $skip: Number(skip) },
        { $limit: Number(limit) },
        {
            $lookup: {
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'conversation_id',
                from: 'message_details',
                as: 'messages'
            }
        },
        { '$unwind': '$messages' },
        { $match: { 'messages.receiver_uid': Number(uid) } },
        { $match: { 'messages.status': 1 } },
        { $sort: { 'messages.created': 1 } },
        {
            $lookup: {
                localField: 'messages.message_id',
                foreignField: '_id',
                from: 'messages',
                as: 'messages.content'
            }
        },
        { '$unwind': '$messages.content' },
        { $sort: { 'messages.content.created': -1 } },
        { '$addFields': { 'messages.created': '$messages.content.created' } },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$_id',
                participants: { $first: '$participants' },
                created: { $first: '$created' },
                messages: { $push: '$messages' }
            }
        },

        {
            $project: {
                _id: '$_id',
                participants: '$participants',
                messages: {
                    $slice: ['$messages', Number(messages_limit)]
                },
                updated: { $arrayElemAt: ['$messages.created', 0] }
            }
        },
        { $sort: { 'updated': -1 } }
    ]);
```

this query returns conversation in right order but messages in wrong order of date